# Why is the eccentricity of a parabola 1?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

What I know:

The standard form for a parabola is $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)$, if the axis of symmetry of the parabola is vertical, or $(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$, if the axis of symmetry of the parabola is horizontal.

The "$a$" value is the distance from the vertex $(h, k)$ to the focus.

So for the eccentricity to be $1$, $c/a = 1$, therefore "$c$" must be equivalent to "$a$".

My question:

> How do you represent "$c$" in a parabola? Is "$c$" the same line as "$a$"?

Comment: To answer the title, you may want to resort to polar representation of conic sections. The parabolas follows if $e=1$ is chosen.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/778305) might be useful.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/409) for a discussion in the context of cones. There, we see that the eccentricity of a parabola is $1$ because the "cutting plane" makes the same angle as the cone.

Comment: The $a$ in your parabola formula has a different meaning from the $a$ in the ellipse/hyperbola context (where it measures major vertex distance to the center). The center of a parabola is a point at infinity (on the axis of symmetry), therefore the analogs to $a,c$ from the elliptic/hyperbolic case would be infinite in the parabolic case.

Comment: @robjohn so it's like infinity/infinity = 1 ?

Answer (score 5):

A [well known property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSectionDirectrix.html) of conic sections (ellipse, parabola or hyperbola) is as follows:

> A conic section is the locus of points whose distance from a given
>   point (focus) is proportional to the distance from a given line
>   (directrix). The fixed proportionality ratio $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity.

For $\epsilon<1$ the locus defined above is an ellipse, for $\epsilon=1$ a parabola and for $\epsilon>1$ a hyperbola.

Comment: Could you mathematically explain how e=1 for a parabola ?

Comment: @theenigma017 The answer depends on the definitions of parabola and eccentricity you have in mind. If the above property is taken as a definition, then $e=1$ by definition.

Comment: Now i get it ... :P ... It's been a while